# How do I get a relative path from one path to another in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm hoping there is a built in .NET method to do this, but I'm not finding it.

I have two paths that I know to be on the same root drive, I want to be able to get a relative path from one to the other.

```
string path1 = @"c:\dir1\dir2\";
string path2 = @"c:\dir1\dir3\file1.txt";
string relPath = MysteryFunctionThatShouldExist(path1, path2); 
// relPath == "..\dir3\file1.txt"
```

Does this function exist?  If not what would be the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`Uri` works:

```
Uri path1 = new Uri(@"c:\dir1\dir2\");
Uri path2 = new Uri(@"c:\dir1\dir3\file1.txt");
Uri diff = path1.MakeRelativeUri(path2);
string relPath = diff.OriginalString;
```

Comment: Uri does work but will switch to forward slashes, which is easy enough to fix.  Thanks!

Comment: There is not only forward slashes to take care ! Better add UnescapeDataString. string relPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(diff.OriginalString);

Comment: As of .Net 5 / .Net Core 2 there's also `MakeRelative`; which seems to do the same as `MakeRelativeUri(...).OriginalString`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.makerelative?view=net-5.0

Comment: This does not work for paths with spaces, as those are converted to %20. And the escaped format does not work everywhere in windows. In my case .lnk files.

Comment: Make sure `path1` has a trailing `Path.DirtectorySeparatorChar` or else your relative path will include the inner-most directory name.

Comment: If you use in the path the string "%2E", Uri does not keep it and converts to "." resulting in a wrong relative path

Comment: @MatteoTeoManMangano that's not "wrong" - it is just a different (and arguably: more correct) expression of the *same* value - the `.` character is *explicitly unreserved*; this is different to characters that *must* be escaped to be a valid url, or which are reserved and need to be escaped to express their literal meaning (rather than their reserved meaning)

Answer (score 18):

You could also import the `PathRelativePathTo` function and call it.

e.g.:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Util
{
  [DllImport( "shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PathRelativePathTo" )]
  protected static extern bool PathRelativePathTo( StringBuilder lpszDst,
      string from, UInt32 attrFrom,
      string to, UInt32 attrTo );

  public static string GetRelativePath( string from, string to )
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
    bool result = PathRelativePathTo( builder, from, 0, to, 0 );
    return builder.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, but I had to remove the "protected", otherwise (with VS2012, .NET3.5) I get the error CS1057: "PathRelativePathTo(System.Text.StringBuilder, string, uint, string, uint)': static classes cannot contain protected members"

Comment: Importing win32 API for a simple case like that seems to be overdoing it, though it's nice to know it's possible.

Comment: @FacelessPanda It's hardly overdoing it - the library is almost certainly loaded anyway so using it has zero overhead.

Comment: @FacelessPanda you would be very disappointed to see the .NET Framework source code then! :)  System.Windows.Forms in particular: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms,namespaces

Comment: @AdamPlocher Your given example is not really a surprise though since Windows Forms was never something else than a WinAPI wrapper.